# Mix cmdlets from assembly and psm1 within a single Module manifest

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-module

I have a C# project containing some custom cmdlets and a module manifest that loads them specifying the assembly as RootModule (I'm using PowerShell 3.0).

I'd need to add some cmdlets written in a psm1 file and I would like to export them within the same ModuleManifest.

For instance, if the Module is named MyModule, I tried something like this in my MyModule.psd1:

```
RootModule = '.\MyModule.dll'
...
NestedModules = @('MyModule\MyModule.psm1')
```

All files (MyModule.psd1, MyModule.dll and MyModule.psm1) are contained in a MyModule directory in a path referenced by the PSModulePath string.

The module is loaded with all cmdlets from the assembly, but I can't see the exported functions (Export-ModuleMember -Function "*") from the .psm1 file.
Is it possible what I'm trying to do? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Current folder from `MyModule.psd1` perspective is the folder where you keep all files, so it should work as soon as you remove (not existing) folder `MyModule` from `Nestedmodules` path.

Comment: Thanks of or your answer. Anyway I had originally tried with the name only (both with and without the prefix ".\" but it didn't work and that's why I tried specifying the module folder too.